# Can be code of SharePoint hosted app which is written in Angular 2.0, move to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, angular2

I have created SharePoint hosted app which is written in Angular 2.0 in the SharePoint 2013, now I want to use this app's code to SharePoint 2010. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you going to use it? if its going to be hosted still in the 2013 environment then it would be fine as you could use an iframe so it would be run under the 2013 environment. If you want to host it and use it in 2010 then no. The rest services in 2010 are not grate so you should go the webpart route or better yet client side JSOM.

Comment: Hi Ali, we are not going to host in the 2013 environment. We have 10 SharePoint hosted apps in angularjs 2 and need to migrate into SharePoint 2010 in short time. So looking for any good solution..

Comment: why dont you host them in azure?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however due to security reason we can't do this, only SharePoint on premises is allowed..